# How to make netlify ignore gitignore and see all files

Tags: github, netlify

I ignored the firebase.js file containing the Firebase data URL with gitignore.

However, as shown in the picture below, netlify showed a message saying that firebase.js could not be found.
To solve this problem, I want to give netlify permission to ignore gitignore and see all files. Could you answer me how?

[image: error]

```bash
npm run build
Failed to compile
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './firebase.js' in '/opt/build/repo/src'
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I think there’s a pretty fundamental misunderstanding here: files you have not committed to the repo do not exist remotely. They aren’t added with some flag to say “ignore this” they aren’t added _at all_. Given that, what is the question (please edit to clarify)?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying. I was asking how to make netlify ignore gitignore and see all files.

Comment: Please don’t ignore the first comment. Let’s start with the simplest question: Does the file `firebase.js` exist in this repo?

Comment: I agree with AD7six.
Is `firebase.js` in the gitignore?

Comment: firebase.js exists but I ignored with gitignore

Comment: Note that `.gitignore` only affects adding new files to a repo - if e.g. you can't see that file in your repo on github, that's not github reading your `.gitignore` file and hiding things, _it means the file is not in the repo_. Alternatively: Please add the output of `git ls-files firebase.js` to the question (if there's no output - this again confirms the file has not been added to the repo).

Answer (score 2):

A typical [React `.gitignore`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/.gitignore) would *not* ignore `firebase.js`, especially considering that file, as [shown here](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/react/react-with-nosql/adding-firebase-to-react#step-3-create-configuration-file-and-initialize-firebase), is where you initialize Firebase in our application and create a database reference.

You can check that with:

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git check-ignore -v -- src/firebase.js
```

But even if it is ignored, that should not prevent the `npm build` to run.